# Navigate to a ViewController from AppDelegate after Google Firebase login is finished

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have integrated `Firebase`, `Google Sign In` in my ios app's `AuthViewController` (Set as `initial ViewController`).

Once user has signed in using Google sign in button, He is redirected back to the 
same `AuthViewController` (i.e. showing the Google Sign In button though he is signed In).

**Question:**

Is there any way i can configure redirect to a particular `ViewController` after User has signed in ? If not i need to know how can i do it programmatically in `AppDelegate`'s using below function

```
 func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            // ...
            return
        }

        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                // ...
                return
            }
            // User is signed in
            // ...
        }
    }
```

I already have a segue defined in my `AuthViewController` to segue to the `MainViewController`, But looks like Firebase authentication is a async call and `userAuthenticated()` function returns `false` by the time we call in `viewDidAppear` function

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("--------View Did Appear \(userAuthenticated())")
        if userAuthenticated() {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMain", sender: nil)
        }
    }


   func userAuthenticated() -> Bool {
        return (Auth.auth().currentUser != nil) ? true : false
    }
```

EDIT:
With Yarn's approach, Though it solves the problem .. but it first shows `AuthViewController`'s view and then segues to `MainViewController` ... Its a bad UI experience to show .. I want user to directly goto `MainViewController` once signed in.

Answer (score 1):

To programmatically segue from AppDelegate you could call

```
if let rootVC = window?.rootViewController {
    rootVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: What will be the `segue` identifier in this case ? I mean what will be the `source` controller and `destination` controller ?

Comment: Your segue identifier is "showMain". The root view controller would be your `AuthViewController` since you set it as initial view controller. The destination would be the `MainViewController` at the other end of the "showMain" segue.

Comment: Is your `AuthViewController` embedded in UINavigationController?

Comment: Cool.. So, Yarn just to understand, Do you know if this Is right design approach to handle this case of case ? FYI, I am just trying to build my first app  :)

Comment: No Yarn .. Its independent viewController

Comment: I don't know best design approach for this situation. Congrats on your first app! :)

Comment: Yarn, Your information has helped me partially .. I just edited my question with the approach i took